# $f_n$ converges uniformly $\iff f_n$ is uniformly Cauchy

Tags: real-analysis

> $f_n\rightarrow f$ uniformly $\iff f_n$ is uniformly Cauchy

$\Rightarrow$:

There exists $N$ s.t. for $m>n>N$ we have:

$$|f_n(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon \Rightarrow |f_n(x)-f(x)|+|f(x)-f_m(x)|<2 \epsilon$$ which implies that its uniformaly Cauchy for the same $N$.

However I'm having slight trouble with $\Leftarrow$:

I know $|f_m-f_n|<\epsilon$. Should I used Cauchy implies bounded and hence there exists a subsequence converging to $f$?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result is misstated in my opinion: It should read "$f_n$ converges uniformly iff $f_n$ is uniformly Cauchy". (How can we show "$f_n$ is uniformly Cauchy" implies "$f_n \to f$ uniformly" when there is no $f$ in the hypotheses?)

Hint: Assume $f_n$ is uniformly Cauchy. Then for each $x$ in the domain, the sequence of real numbers $(f_n(x))$ is Cauchy in $\mathbb R.$ Hence $\lim_{n\to \infty}f_n(x)$ exists in $\mathbb R.$ Call this limit $f(x).$ Only now do you have a specific function to aim at. Show now that $f_n$ converges uniformly to this $f.$

Comment: by show, you mean just take the limit? Unless I misunderstood the proof is trivial after taking the limit, now that we know it exists, since its cauchy

Comment: Nicely written ... as always.  +1

Comment: @GRS It's not hard but it should be done.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: use that $|f_n - f_m| < \epsilon$ and take $\lim_{m \rightarrow +\infty}$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$\lim_{m \to \infty} |f_m(x) - f_n(x)|  = |f(x) - f_n(x)|$$

Answer (score 1):

You should be aware of the fact that $\exists f,f_m\to f $, if $f_m$ is a Cauchy sequence.(Why?,Because $L^\infty(R)$ is a Banach space, every Cauchy Sequence converges.) Then combined with @Luísa Borsato's answer. It's done.

Comment: Thanks, I was unaware of this fact